How to recover from deleted Windows 10 boot manager?
I had two separate EFI partitions. I formatted both of them and installed grub on one (to use Linux), meaning I deleted Windows boot manager files. I flashed an installation medium and opened cmd in it. When I type
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\grub\grubx64.efi

Or
bootrec /rebuildbcd

It finds Windows but I get the same error for both commands:

"The requested system device cannot be identified due to multiple indistinguishable devices potentially matching the identification criteria."

What should I do? Should I delete my grub files and retry? If I delete grub files I can fix them by booting into the Artix installation medium and this time configuring grub into the correct EFI partition (same as Windows).

If you deleted the EFI then you will have to reinstall Windows so the EFI partition can be recreated. You deleted the partition Windows requires to boot


First make a complete, verified, drive image. There are many tools to do so, such as Macrium Reflect Free and numerous alternatives.

Then try downloading the Windows 10 ISO using "Create Windows 10 installation media", and try repairing, keeping files. If that succeeds, then your issue should be resolved.

If that fails, then remove all partitions, leaving the drive space unassigned, reinstall Windows, and finally restore the previous Windows and data partitions from the drive image.


At the very worst, you can always restore the whole drive image to start over, should there be further issues.
